# Broadband (wired) stopped working after a reboot - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64

Tags: networking, 16.04, ethernet

Switched to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from WinXP a month back. Internet(wired broadband connection) was working flawlessly for few weeks.

I'm guessing some automatic updates or something I fiddled with network-connections has rendered it useless on Ubuntu environment.

- My system stays on for multiple days between reboots.
- System registers(Authentication username/password) properly with Broadband service provider on LAN. i.e DHCP is working fine.
- `ping www.google.com` or `tracepath www.google.com` times out. Although DNS resolution happens properly.
- Same wired connection is working properly on another Win10 laptop.

Tried :

- Disabled IPv6
- Manual configuration of `interfaces` file

Any help in this regard will be grateful.

Please ask for any further inputs/data needed to troubleshoot this issue.

Edit:

- Output of the Diagnostics: [wireless-info.txt](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16785693/)
- Script : [wireless-info - github](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info)

Ping Status (LAN/Public IP) :

```
spark@lenovo-g570:/var/log$ ping 172.16.10.1 -c 4
PING 172.16.10.1 (172.16.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.648 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.694 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.10.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.714 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.10.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.715 ms

--- 172.16.10.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.648/0.692/0.715/0.042 ms



spark@lenovo-g570:/var/log$ ping 8.8.8.8 -c 4
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=9.52 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=9.53 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=9.61 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=9.58 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 9.528/9.564/9.618/0.078 ms
```

Traceroute:

```
spark@lenovo-g570:~$ sudo traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Host DNS lookup:

```
spark@lenovo-g570:~$ host google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

spark@lenovo-g570:~$ sudo host google.com 8.8.8.8
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

---

### Update

Since I couldn't narrow down to the actual issue, I re-installed Ubuntu-16.04LTS after necessary backups.
cheers

Comment: Nice script, give me few minutes. brb with the data

Comment: @DavidFoerster Diagnostics output uploaded, please have a look.

Comment: What's the output of `ping -c 4 172.16.10.1` (the local gateway) and `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8` (Google's public DNS server)? If the former works but not the latter, can you please also try `traceroute 8.8.8.8` (works for me while `tracepath` doesn't for some reason)? Mask your public IP address if you wish.

Comment: @DavidFoerster `traceroute` is not present on this system but `traceroute6` is. Let me see if it works with `Google
Public DNS IPv6 addresses:

2001:4860:4860::8888
2001:4860:4860::8844`

Comment: @DavidFoerster apparently our LAN is not ready. IPv6 addresses are unreachable even for `ping6`. I've to disconnect on one laptop and connect on the other to test/collect data, hence it takes little time.

Comment: Looks like at least IPv4 is working fine. According to the wireless diagnostic script you had IPv6 disabled. Let's see if DNS works with `host google.com` vs. `host google.com 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Yes, IPv6 was disabled then. I installed `traceroute` from `.deb` files. brb

Comment: @DavidFoerster nothing came out from `traceroute` and `host` lookup.

Comment: It looks like something on your machine or network is blocking DNS requests. That is the most plausible explanation why `ping 8.8.8.8` works but `host google.com 8.8.8.8` doesn't.